# Xe-135 Binding Energy - Calculations Not Agreeing With Reported Values

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

I am trying to calculate the binding energy of Xe-135 using the following equation:

\begin{equation}
BE = \Delta{}c^2
\end{equation}

Where $\Delta{}$ is the mass defect:
\begin{equation}
\Delta{} = ZM_p + NM_n - M_X
\end{equation}
and $N = (A-Z)$. Using the values listed below, I am calculating a binding energy of ~1106 MeV. However, [Appendix B](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9783527618798.app2) of Physics for Radiation Protection lists the value as ~1133.8MeV. Is there a flaw in my approach to calculating the binding energy? Possibly some energy contribution that is missing? I have seen calculations of the [binding energy including the semi empirical mass formula](http://www.hep.ph.ic.ac.uk/%7Edauncey/will/lecture19.pdf). Is the equation I have listed here a first order approximation, and the SEMF a better approach for more accurate results?

\begin{equation}
Z=54\\ 
A=135\\ 
(M_p, M_n, M_x) = (1.007u, 1.008u, 134.907u)\\ 
c^2=931.5MeV/u
\end{equation}

Comment: The difference is suspiciously close to the mass of the electrons.

Comment: The Atomic Mass Evaluation (2016) lists the Mass excess of Xe-135 as -86413 keV.

Comment: To answer your question at the end:  The equation you've provided is the *definition* of binding energy, so by definition it's more accurate than the SEMF.  (More complicated does not mean more accurate!)